# Data not visible after accessing windows

Tags: data-recovery

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8. I restarted my laptop to check Windows 8 for the first time. But the content showed in the file explorer was not what I had saved in Ubuntu. When I restarted again, and logged in to Ubuntu, the data is not at all visible in one partition and only some of it are visible in the other partition, but the memory space is still occupied(as seen in right-click-->properties). How do I recover the data?
The data is there, how do I see it?

Comment: Where is the data? In a NTFS partition or inside Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 has a feature called fast startup, where it actually does not shut down, but hibernates instead.  If you hibernate one OS then try to access the same filesystem from another, it will be corrupted.  You will need to run scandisk to repair the damage, and in the future, either disable the fast startup feature, or make sure you always reboot into Ubuntu instead of shutdown, then turn the power on and boot into Ubuntu ( while Windows is now really hibernated ).